# How to add peak elevation values?

Tags: elevation

How do I add peak elevation values to a topographic map?  Also, is it possible to display the numeric value in feet?

I'm using the studio, looking at Terrain > Terrain Labels, which only seems to apply to the contour lines but not the peak elevations. Also looked at Natural Features > Natural Point Labels and tried modifying the text field value to:

coalesce(name_en, name, to-string(elevation_ft))

which yielded nothing

Comment: Please add the name of the  programming language or technology you're using.